# como esconder subpastas da url atraves .htacess

Tags: htaccess, url, url-amigável, url-rewrite

Olá! 
como fazer alteração de uma url através do 'htacess'. queria que essa url:

```
http://localhost/site/product/view/Mi00OTI/golbolaver
```

ficasse assim:

```
http://localhost/site/view/Mi00OTI/golbolaver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução rápida

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^site/view/Mi00OTI/golbolaver(|/)$ site/product/view/Mi00OTI/golbolaver
```

Leia mais em

> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/pt-br/howto/htaccess.html